# Get First Element from Collection and delete it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to get the first element from a Firebase Collection and then delete it, but can't figure out how to do it. I need it for a cloud function.

```
await ref
      .doc(ref.limit(1).get().docs[0]);
```

Comment: what data structure is considered under 'Collection'? please provide some example of the data you deal with

Comment: Do you want it to be deleted from javascript collection (array,object). then you can try this collection.shift(); collection - here is array.

Comment: Meant a Firebase collection @bohkoval

Comment: You need to define what is the "first" element.  Documents in a collection don't have an order other than what you choose, based on the values of fields you add.

Comment: So I have to get the document Id from the first element? How do I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bohkoval's overall logic, as presented in his/her answer is correct, however the answer is related to the **Realtime Database**, while the OP is working with **Firestore** (from the tags used in his question).

Making the assumption that you "have a timestamp property which [you] can sort by" as you said in the comment below, in a Cloud Function you would do as follows for Firestore:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("yourCollection")
.orderBy("yourTimestamp", "desc")
.limit(1)
.get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        //We know there is one doc in the querySnapshot
        const queryDocumentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
        return queryDocumentSnapshot.ref.delete();
    } else {
        console.log("No document corresponding to the query!");
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't figure out how to get the reference or id...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `delete()` method on the desired element.

Firebase collection is not ordered data type, so there is no such notion as "first element". But you can `add()` some flag (for example, a timestamp) in order to distinguish which element was added firstly. Firebase collection itself doesn't have any built-in flag to detect an element as "first".

For example, if you have timestamp flag:

```
var collection = firebase.database().ref('/path/to/collection');
var collectionLast = collection.orderByChild('timestamp').limit(1);
var listener = collectionLast.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref.remove();
});
```

1. get collection reference
2. order elements by timestamp (it will be done in ascending order), limit to first element
3. when this element is retrieved from the collection, `child_added` event is triggered with the snapshot payload and remove it.

Also, if you need it for cloud function, pay attention to `value` event. You need to change 3rd step to the following code;

```
collectionLast.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
```

For more info you can grab the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: I have a timestamp property which I can sort by, but I don't get how to delete the element.